# Triggering Bootstrap modal on navigation link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently just started a site for a client, and I'm getting into Bootstrap, Also I'm new to this site. I have the site layout down which is pretty simple. Full width page with "Top Nav" within the nav bar, and I would like to create a modal effect drop down. so for example when you click on "About" this should trigger the .modal function and a simple page will cover the background image and have a bio. However I get no response when I click on the "About" tab  I've attached my code below, Please help I'm getting nothing, also I'm using DreamWeaver.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Kameechi</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/Rae.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
 font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}
    </style>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<head>
<body style="background-image:url(assets/images/Kameechi.gif)">
<div class="topBar">
<span class="left">
<a class="cornerlogo" href="/"><img src="assets/images/kuh.png"></a>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">ABOUT</a>
<a class="vids" href="#">VIDEOS</a>
<a class="feed" href="#">FEED</a>
<a class="music" href="#">MUSIC</a>
<a class="news" href="#">NEWS</a>
<a class="tour" href="#">TOUR</a>
<a class="shop" target="_blank" href="">SHOP</a>
</span>
<span class="right">
<a class="soundcloud" href="https://soundcloud.com/"> </a>
<a class="insta" href="https://instagram.com/"> </a>
<a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/"> </a>
<a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/"> </a>
<a class="audiomack" href="https://www.audiomack.com/artist/"> </a>
  <!-------------------- Modal --------------------->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  Modal content here....
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<script id="backgrounds" type="text/html">
</script>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googl...ility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
    .modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -300%;
    transition: top 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#music.modal {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 2, 0.9) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#tour.modal {
    background: rgba(255, 20, 2, 0.9) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.modal span {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 0 9%;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#bio {
    color: white;
    margin: 100px 20%;
    text-align: left;
}
#feed, #music, #tour_modal, #bio_modal {
    display: table;
    overflow: scroll;
}
body.feed .blog, body.feed .videos, body.tour .blog, body.tour .videos, body.bio .blog, body.bio .videos {
    display: none;
}
body.music #music, body.feed #feed, body.tour #tour_modal, body.bio #bio_modal {
    top: 0;
}
#tour_modal {
    top: -1600px;
}
body.bio .close {
    top: 40px;
}
body.bio #logo, body.bio .mask, body.tour #logo, body.tour .mask, body.news #logo, body.news .mask, body.news .latest, body.feed #logo, body.feed .mask, body.feed .latest, body.music #logo, body.music .mask, body.music .latest, body.videos #logo, body.videos .mask, body.videos .latest {
    display: none !important;
}
.close {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: -100%;
    transition: top 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.close:hover {
    color: white;
```

Comment: What do you click to trigger the modal?

Comment: Uh...do you have any more HTML to share? Because there seems to be quite a lot of unclosed/unopened elements in your snippet.

Comment: As @Serlite said...there's a lot missing here, which could be causing the problem. If my answer doesn't work, you've definitely have issues elsewhere.

Comment: html shown doesn't make sense and doesn't match docs

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response Still learning this forum. I updated to what I have so far with HTML. I want to click "About" Section to trigger this

Comment: So I've added the updated html  and css thanks to @Serlite I also added the modal div code minus the buttons (because I want it to point directly to about) thanks to "jonmrich", I think I'm getting closer anymore suggestions please feel free to post. Still getting stuck. Thanks Again

Comment: This `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">ABOUT</a>` should be this `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ABOUT</a>`

Comment: @jonmrich that has been changed. Once I refresh the page, it is no longer clickable. I feel like I'm getting dumber lol

Comment: @jonmrich I forgot to mention I added that in the code, Still noting.

Comment: See updated answer that addresses your specific code. Easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  ABOUT
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  Modal content here....
</div>
```

You obviously don't need to use a button as long as you add the `data-toggle` and `data-target` to the item you want to use as your trigger.

The problem with your code in your answer is that you're closing your spans and divs for your menu AFTER the modal's div. These need to be closed BEFORE your modal divs start. Like this:

```
<div class="topBar">
<span class="left">
<a class="cornerlogo" href="/"><img src="assets/images/kuh.png"></a>

    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">ABOUT</a>
<a class="vids" href="#">VIDEOS</a>
<a class="feed" href="#">FEED</a>
<a class="music" href="#">MUSIC</a>
<a class="news" href="#">NEWS</a>
<a class="tour" href="#">TOUR</a>
<a class="shop" target="_blank" href="">SHOP</a>
</span>
<span class="right">
<a class="soundcloud" href="https://soundcloud.com/"> </a>
<a class="insta" href="https://instagram.com/"> </a>
<a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/"> </a>
<a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/"> </a>
<a class="audiomack" href="https://www.audiomack.com/artist/"> </a>
    </span>
</div>

  <!-------------------- Modal --------------------->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style=" overflow: scroll; height:auto;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 Body
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonmrich/jpotsewv/  (click on ABOUT to trigger modal)

PS: not sure why you included the CSS in your answer. That looks like the standard Bootstrap CSS, which you're already calling with this: `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`. If you include the CSS a second time, you might be causing some issues with the modal as well.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I now see a tint over the page once "About" is selected however no content lol

Comment: That's a CSS issue. Read the PS part of my answer and double check that you're not doing this. If you add the CSS to the jsfiddle I made you'll see the same thing. My guess is that you're calling that twice.

Comment: The reason why Im calling two CSS one is the standard bootstrap the other is specifically for the layout. if I get rid of that one it will throw the whole site off, so essentially I need to override the core bootstrap to fit my custom css.

Comment: It looks like you can just delete the first bit of your CSS (for the attribute `.modal`) and then it'll work fine. That shouldn't affect your site. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonmrich/jpotsewv/2/